# scale_x_discrete not displaying altered axis labels

Tags: r

I've been trying to alter my x-axis labels. Currently, it displays all the years in my dataset, I'd like to display them in a given interval. When I use scale_x_discrete as set up below, all the axis tick marks disappear, instead of listing the years in intervals of ten from 1970

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020), labels = c("1970", "1980", "1990", "2000", "2010", "2020"))
```

Comment: Hi Jack, in order to help you we need a sample of your data in order to reproduce your issue, could you please add a sample of your data?

Comment: It's still a continuous scale - numbers are continuous (at least as far as `ggplot` is concerned). If the column you're mapping to the x-axis is numeric, then `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1970, 2020, by = 10))` should do the trick. If your data column is `factor`, then I'd suggest converting it to `numeric`. If you need more help, please, as Duck says, share some data. `dput()` is the nicest way to share data, as  it is copy/pasteable and preserves class and structure, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])`

Comment: it gives me "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" when I use scale_x_continuous. Is this because my data is factor and not numeric?

Comment: Probably. Try converting it. Or examining the data (`class(your_data$your_column)`, or `str(your_data)`). And if you need more help, please share some data so we can see what you've got.